# How long can I wait before staining a new deck?

Tags: deck, staining, winterizing

I just moved into a new (well, old) house.  The previous owners put in a deck probably about 1 year ago.  It's treated lumber, but they hadn't yet stained it.  Winter is approaching quickly here in upstate NY, so I'd like to wait until Spring if I can.  But I'm concerned that letting it sit unstained through the winter will have long term effects on the wood.  So, can I wait?  or should I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It'll be fine.  You should always wait at least one year anyways to make sure the wood is fully dried.  I think I waited almost 3 years before I stained parts of my deck, with no detrimental effects.

Answer (score 0):

1 full year is usually enough time before staining treated lumber.  If you are worried about it wait one more year.

When the wood starts to change colors is a sure sign it is okay.